# Hive Query FAILED: ParseException line cannot recognize input near '(' 'WITH' 'DATA_SET' in select clause

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I get a failure upon compiling a Hive View query using "WITH" Clause in the select statement. Below is the same view which I try to create and I encounter the error.

```
create view test_view as(
with data_set as
(select * from test_data )
select * from data_set
) ;
```

> **Error - Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:24 cannot recognize input near '(' 'with' 'data_set' in select
>   clause**

Please help.

Comment: why do you need a `with` here exactly? Why not just `create view as select * `?

Comment: This is a sample code I share you... but in real case I need this "WITH" clause in the select query because I can avoid multiple time fetching from same table in unions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is due to the bracket :)

once I remove the bracket from after create view view_name as **(***.. it stated working...